# Proper way to zoom dynamic created webview

Tags: javascript, webview, electron

I create a webview dynamically in my BrowserWindow in Electron.

```
  var webviewlo = document.createElement("webview");
  webviewlo.src = 'http://google.com';
  webviewlo.id = 'loo';
  webviewlo.preload = "./preload.js";
  webviewlo.style = 'height: 100%; width: 100%';
  loElement.appendChild(webviewlo);
```

For example I want (like in Chrome) to zoom inside the webview.

I did in the preload.js:

```
var webview = document.getElementById("loo");
webview.style = 'transform: scale(0.8)';
```

But it doesn't change anything.

What is the proper way to zoom in electron webviews?

Thank in advance

Comment: Why do you need to set the zoom in the preload.js? Could you not use webviewlo.style = 'height: 100%; width: 100%; transform: scale(2.0)';?

Comment: Yes, your answer worked, I dont know why it doesnt at the first time, but now it is working. You removed it?

Comment: Glad to hear it! I removed it as I thought I did not understand what you were asking since it was not working. I have since put it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to set the zoom successfully after the 'did-stop-loading' event fires. Try:

```
  var webview = document.getElementById('loo');
  webview.addEventListener('did-stop-loading', function() {
    webview.setZoomFactor(0.8);
  }, false);
```